# Why does GetGenericTypeDefinition fail?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics

I have a piece of code which needs to check an entity when being saved by my Repository. I have an NHibernate interceptor on the save to check this but when I call the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` function the code fails with the error:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      System.RuntimeType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() +7525641

Code is this:

```
protected override object PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent evt)
{
    if (evt.Entity.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IChild<>))
    {
        var parent = (evt.Entity as IChild<Entity>).Parent;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.UpdateCacheCounters();
            evt.Session.Save(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you see whether evt.Entity.GetType() itself already fails? It would help to know exactly what function call fails in this example. The exception does not look like an exception returned from GetGenericTypeDefinition().

Comment: It does not fail to get evt.Entity.GetType()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Type type = evt.Entity.GetType();
if(
    type.IsGenericType && 
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IChild<>)
)
```

try this. according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx:

> InvalidOperationException: The current
>   type is not a generic type. That is,
>   IsGenericType returns false.

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now you have shown me but was just not seeing it. Appreciate the help.