# System.InvalidOperationException when setting up constructor injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, restsharp

I am trying to inject a constructor parameter using Ninject:

```
    private void AddBindings()
    {
        //_kernel.Bind<IRestClient>().ToConstructor(x => new RestClient("http://localhost:49780/api/ProductApi"));
        _kernel.Bind<IRestClient>().ToConstructor(x => new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"]));
    }
```

However I get the following `System.InvalidOperationException`

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

It works fine when I use the commented out line instead.
I have checked in debug mode that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"]` is equal to `"http://localhost:49780/api/ProductApi"`.

Why is this Exception being thrown?

Here's the `StackTrace`:

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingBuilder.AddConstructorArgument(Expression argument, String argumentName, ParameterExpression constructorArgumentSyntaxParameterExpression)
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingBuilder.AddConstructorArguments(NewExpression ctorExpression, ParameterExpression constructorArgumentSyntaxParameterExpression)
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingBuilder.InternalToConstructor[TImplementation](Expression`1 newExpression)
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingBuilder`1.ToConstructor[TImplementation](Expression`1 newExpression)
   at ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver.AddBindings() in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCart\Infrastructure\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:line 35
   at ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver..ctor(IKernel kernelParam) in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCart\Infrastructure\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:line 20
   at ShoppingCart.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCart\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:line 56
   at ShoppingCart.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel() in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCart\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:line 46
   at Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback)
   at ShoppingCart.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCart\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:line 25
```

**EDIT:**

I just realised it works fine if I do this:

```
    string productsApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"];
    _kernel.Bind<IRestClient>().ToConstructor(x => new RestClient(productsApiUrl));
```

Why does it matter when `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"]` is evaluated?

I had a look at `AddConstructorArgument()` on [GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingBuilder.cs).
It has the following if statement:

```
if (!(argument is MethodCallExpression methodCall) ||
                !methodCall.Method.IsGenericMethod ||
                methodCall.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().DeclaringType != typeof(IConstructorArgumentSyntax))
```

The fact that it is calling `GetGenericMethodDefinition()` means that `!methodCall.Method.IsGenericMethod` is `false`, ie. `IsGenericMethod` returns `true`.

However according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getgenericmethoddefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) `InvalidOperationException` is thrown only if `IsGenericMethod` returns `false`.

So I'm confused as to how the `InvalidOperationException` is being thrown at all.

Comment: Where does the exception get thrown from? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @OwenPauling I have put the stack trace in the question.

Comment: `Why does it matter when ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"] is evaluated?` With your working code it is reading it at registration time. With your non-working code it is reading it at resolution time. As to why one works and one doesn't, I am not sure...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969618/why-does-getgenerictypedefinition-fail looks related, but I don't know enough of Ninject to know for sure.

Comment: Which version of Ninject do you use? Can't reproduce this.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky it's v3.0.1.10

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I'm now using 3.3.4 and I'm no longer getting the error. However it would be interesting to know why it was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there was a bug in old version. When decompiling with Resharper, I can see there was no `IsGenericMethod` check, but just:

```
  if (methodCallExpression != null && !(methodCallExpression.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().DeclaringType != typeof (IConstructorArgumentSyntax)))
    return;
```

Then `GetGenericMethodDefinition()` will fail, because your expression - `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"]` is not generic.

Comment: But ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"] is of type string, and so is "http://localhost:49780/api/ProductApi", and neither are generic.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, the point is that argument of `ToConstructor` method is evaluated as `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` therefore `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsApiUrl"]` will be evaluated as `MethodCallExpression` whereas the other one as `ConstantExpression`.